# Angular 6 CLI error while creating a new component

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem when trying to create a new component.

The error is :

> More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to generate the component by explicitly stating the module in which you want to import it.

For example,

```
ng g component my-component --module <module_name>
```

Comment: Thanks my pro ! this command worked for me : "ng g component my-component --module app"

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to explain Why this happens. Basically you have 2 or more modules under your src/app folder.

**e.g:**

- app.module.ts
- hero.module.ts

The Angular CLI is not smart enough to know that you want to put the new component under the app.module.

2 solutions to fix this issue

1) create a new folder under src/app and put the other modules you have at the same level of app.module inside of this new folder you just created.

2) ng generate component name_of_component --module app (short hand ng g c name_of_component)

Doing the step number one will avoid you having to enter everytime **--module app**

Comment: I appreciate a lot your clarification, Thanks Bro

Comment: No problem! we are here to help